# jQuery animation performing strangely due to excessive events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I have a gallery on my site. Each image is a `<div>` which has a background image. The overflow is hidden, and I hide a caption `div` using margin. I then use the following jQuery to animate the captions when the mouse enters and leaves the picture `<div>`.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".gallery-image", function(){
    $(this).children(".caption").dequeue();
    $(this).children(".caption").fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 500}).animate({marginTop: "350px"}, 500);
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".gallery-image", function(){
    $(this).children(".caption").dequeue();
    $(this).children(".caption").fadeOut({queue: false, duration: 500}).animate({marginTop: "400px"}, 500);
});
```

When I move the mouse in and out too fast weird things start to happen. The caption stays half-faded, or the caption simply stops appearing altogether.

The problem can be seen in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eh4Ls4sh/2/).

Why am I getting this unexpected behavior?

Comment: Added a link to a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.stop(true, true)` to stop the pre queues of the animations

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".gallery-image", function(){
        $(this).children(".caption").stop(true,true).fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 500}).animate({marginTop: "350px"}, 500);
 });
    $(document).on("mouseleave", ".gallery-image", function(){
        $(this).children(".caption").stop(true,true).fadeOut({queue: false, duration: 500}).animate({marginTop: "400px"}, 500);
 });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eh4Ls4sh/3/)